# Sony Vaio VPCEE2E1E memory upgrade issue

Tags: memory, bios, sony-vaio

I own Sony Vaio laptop VPCEE2E1E and I recently upgraded RAM MEMORY from default 3GB to 4GB after that operation I'm facing serious problem with performance.Windows shows that I have only 1.74GB memory usable out of 4GB installed.BIOS sees those 4GB.
I tried to reverse all to what it was before by putting original memory stick back in place but no luck,there is still only 1.74 GB memory usable no matter what I do and the rest is being hardware reserved.
Before the upgrade everything was fine and my system was using all 3GB of installed memory.
The memory stick I upgraded my laptop with was
"Samsung 2GB DDR3 PC3-8500S 1066MHZ"
The steps I took to resolve this issue don't work :

1.Reinstalled and updated Windows 7 64 bit
2.Updated Bios
3.Maximum memory box in msconfig was and is unchecked.
4.I ran Windows Memory Diagnostic tool and there was no errors reported.
4a. I ran memtest from Parted Magic's usb and no errors too.
5.Tried swiching sticks in slots several possible combinations plus tried other sticks too.

As I said none of above worked so how can I get this fixed any ideas?

PS.I found some info about tempering with shared memory settings in the BIOS but unfortunately those settings seem to bo locked down by Sony so I simply have no access to.
No matter how much memory I add all is taken and hardware reserved and what's left is 1.74GB.

Comment: I just fixed a Vaio with a similar problem. I swapped the two 2GB sticks and it seemed to work; I'm guessing I could have reseated them in the same spot and it would've also fixed it.